# Google chart Showing zero in case of missing date in bar graph

Tags: google-visualization, bar-chart, linechart

I have an object which contains "Date" and "Amount".The object will contain the data for last seven days.If any one date is missing in the object I want to show the bar graph as 0 for that date.
Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer .Incase if any one require you can have a look at below code

```
 var orders = _orderService.GetAll(c => c.RestaurantId == restaurantId && (c.Date > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7))).OrderBy(x => x.Date).GroupBy(item => item.Date.Date).OrderBy(g => g.Key).
                    Select(i => new Order { Date = i.Key.Date, GrossAmount = i.Sum(w => w.GrossAmount) }).ToList();
        var from = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);

        var to = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

        var days = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + to.Subtract(from).Days)
              .Select(offset => from.AddDays(offset))
              .ToArray();

        var data = days.Select(i =>new Order{ Date=i.Date,GrossAmount=orders.Where(p=>p.Date==i.Date).Sum(w=>w.GrossAmount)}).ToList();
```